# In which order was the template parameter used?

Tags: c++, g++, name-mangling

Consider the following two (similar) symbols: `_Z3fooIicEvT_iT0_` and `_Z3fooIicEvT0_iT_`.

`c++filt` gives the following output:

```
> c++filt _Z3fooIicEvT_iT0_
void foo<int, char>(int, int, char)

> c++filt _Z3fooIicEvT0_iT_
void foo<int, char>(char, int, int)
```

This does not tell us in which order the template parameter were used as function parameters.

Notice, however, that the symbols end differently (`T_iT0_` vs `T0_iT_`), where:

- `T_` = 1st template parameter
- `T0_` = 2nd template parameter

So there actually is information available to also print the more generic template declaration.

For example, on the following format:
`template<typename T_, typename T0_> void foo(T_, int, T0_);`

or
`template<typename T_, typename T0_> void foo(T0_, int, T_);`

Is there a simple way to retrieve this information?

(And no, I don't want to implement a parser that can interpret the full IA64 C++ ABI specification)

Comment: If they were used as template parameters at all. The best is still to look at the header to see what prototype `foo` has.